# Alpine js x-text not defined after drag and drop operation

Tags: alpine.js

Hi all alpine js geeks,

I am trying to set datatransfer property of drag and drop api with the html of the current html element.

```
<span draggable="true" class="dropdown-item fs-6 cursor-pointer databoard-grid-draggable" 
:id="$id('databoard-grid-draggable')" @dragstart="
    (event) => {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.innerHTML);    
    }
">
    <i class="fa fa-fw me-2" :class="module.icon"></i>
    <span x-text="module.name"></span>
</span>
```

However, when this element is dropped at certain dropping place and I am trying to pickup the html which was set via dataTransfer method this way, Alpine js is re-evaluating x-text attribute at that drop place and giving error about module being not defined.

```
@drop.prevent="(event) => {
        $(event.target).html(event.dataTransfer.getData('text'))
    }"
```

`Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`

Obviously it gives this error due to x-data for module is not defined at dropping place.
I can of course prepare html in that dragstart function via string concatenation in same fashion as inner html and then set dataTransfer's text but it feels somewhat cumbersome.

How to strip out those `x-` attributes or any other alpine attributes from html so that it does not complaint about the data is not defined?

Comment: You can try to add the [`x-ignore` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/ignore) to the element before moving so Alpine.js will ignore it.

Comment: @Dauros Thanks but what x-ignore does is to prevent alpine js from accessing that entirely. I want that  x-text to be available first but keep that as it is during drag and drop.

Comment: You can remove `x-ignore` after the drop event. Alpine.js uses `MutationObserver` for detecting DOM changes, so it will rerender the component after you remove `x-ignore` directive from the component.